# Change content in persistence.xml dynamically during execution

Tags: java, jpa

For a reason, I need to change content of persistence.xml dynamically during the execution of the program, (using JPA), I need to change address of the host. Is this possible?

Thank you very much

Comment: don't know if this will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6355905/change-values-in-persistence-xml-from-within-the-program

Answer (score 8):

You can use `createEntityManagerFactory(unitName, map)` method to change the `Persistence Context`.
In my example, `Persistence Unit Name` will be dynamicJPA.

Example :

```
protected EntityManager getEntityManager(String driver, String url, String username, String password) {
    EntityManager em = null;
    Map properties = new HashMap();
    properties.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.driver", driver);
    properties.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.url", url);
    properties.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.user", username);
    properties.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.password", password);
    try {
        emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("dynamicJPA", properties);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return em = (EntityManager) emf.createEntityManager();
}
```

You can also use `PersistenceUnitMetaData` of `DataNucleus`.Reference [Dynamically generated Persistence-Unit](http://www.datanucleus.org/products/datanucleus/jpa/persistence_unit.html)

Comment: Works, but it runs extremely slow. Is there another way?